# How to structure this webClient call correctly?

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a method that currently looks like this:

```
protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {
    try {
        VaultHealth vaultHealth = this.webClient
            .get()
            .exchange()
                .block()
                    .bodyToMono(VaultHealth.class)
                        .block();

        if (vaultHealth.isInitialized() && !vaultHealth.isSealed() && !vaultHealth.isStandby()) {
            builder.up();
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        builder.down();
        return;
    }

    builder.down();
}
```

My understanding is that this is wrong. So now I'm looking at fixing it and that it should really be something like:

```
        this.webClient
            .get()
            .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess(???)
                .doOnError(Health.Builder::down);
```

.doOnSuccess is going to return a ClientResponse and I need to actually check stuff in the response before I call Health.Builder::up.

if I call .flatMap() instead of doOnSuccess, is it going to throw on an error? Or do I need to put that inside of the doOnSuccess? If I put it inside of the doOnSuccess, it seems like I need to do a double doOnSuccess (that can't be right, can it?):

```
.doOnSuccess(x -> x.bodyToMono(VaultHealth.class).doOnSuccess(y -> if (y...) builder.up())
```

Also, I assume if I restructure it this way I don't need the try/catch since the doOnError will handle that?

While this particular method makes sense to execute an action when its done, what about scenarios where I need to return the object? My other understanding is that I should never be using .block, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mono::flatMap` is for `asynchronous` operations. A call to WebClient is an "asynchronous" operation so you'll generally need to use `Mono:flatMap` after the `WebClient::exchange` method. No, you should never use `Mono::block` in a "WebFlux" application. Instead of what you have, do it the reactive way:

```
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Health.Builder healthBuilder = new Health.Builder();
        healthBuilder.down();
        doHealthCheck(healthBuilder).onErrorReturn(healthBuilder).map(Health.Builder::build).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
    protected Mono<Health.Builder> doHealthCheck( Health.Builder builder) {
        return webClient
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(VaultHealth.class)
            .map(vaultHealth->{
                if (vaultHealth.isInitialized() && !vaultHealth.isSealed() && !vaultHealth.isStandby())
                    builder.up();
                else 
                    builder.down();
                return builder;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work after all. Looks like some health checks (Eureka to be specific) don't support reactive. So its already returned from the method and gotten an unknown status before the webclient call completes.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Sounds like another question. Note I edited the original answer.